# How to get only last 4 WORKING days data in SAS?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to pull only last 4 working days data in SAS...I tried following code but I'm not getting what I'm intended to...

```
data input;
Input id $ id1 $ id2 $ num date date9.;
Format Date Date9.;
datalines;
x y z 3 19JUL2015
x y z 2 18JUL2015
x y z 3 17JUL2015
x y z 2 16JUL2015
x y z 3 15JUL2015
x y z 2 14JUL2015
x y z 3 13JUL2015
a b c 1 12JUL2015
a b c 1 11JUL2015
a b c 1 10JUL2015
a b c 1 09JUL2015
a b c 1 08JUL2015
a b c 2 07JUL2015
x y z 1 06JUL2015
;
Run;
Data test;
Set input;
Weekday=Weekday(Date);
intck=intck('weekday',Date,today());
*if intck('weekday',Date,today()) >4;
if 1<Weekday(Date)<7 and Date>=today()-4;
Run;
```

Comment: Am I right that you want what that code does, but want to use `intck` (The commented out line) to do it?

Comment: last 4 working days in your dataset, in the month?

Comment: Do bank holidays matter?

Comment: @Joe I want last 4 working days data from any given day...For example if run the code on 26 th, i need 24,23,22,21 dates data..

Comment: @RobertPenridge No, bank holidays doesn't matter. Thanks,Sam.

Comment: @Reeza : last 4 working days in my dataset. Thanks,Sam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to reverse the > in your code, and add a qualification that you only want weekdays:

```
Data test;
  Set input;
  Weekday=Weekday(Date);
  intck=intck('weekday',Date,today());
  if intck('weekday',Date,'20JUL2015'd) le 4 and 1<weekday(Date)<7;
  *if 1<Weekday(Date)<7 and Date>='20JUL2015'd-5;
Run;
```